# How to enable view binding in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, view

my gradle file looks like this - how can I enable view binding.

When I put

```
android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

...

```
Edit:

 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_r_v, container, false)

view.floatingActionButton.setInClickListener
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_RVFragment_to_addFragment)
    


        return view
    }
```

floatingActionButton is always red - so view. didn't find floatingActionButton to connect an onClickListener

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score -1):

You need to inflate your binding like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val view = binding.root
setContentView(view)
```

}

Try this. And if `ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` produces a binding your binding is working in general. This means the problem should be located in your layout XML. Maybe you didn't get the buttons id right?

Also Note: Your Binding class is named after your fragments **name of the xml layout file** not the fragment's class name. If these are different it may cause some confusion.